# Is "conditioning to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra" a measurable operation?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$, and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of probability measures on $([0,1],\mathcal{B})$, equipped with the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra $\ \sigma(\rho \mapsto \rho(A):A \in \mathcal{B})$.

Let $\mathcal{M}_2$ be the set of probability measures on $([0,1] \times [0,1], \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B})$, again equipped with the associated evaluation $\sigma$-algebra $\ \sigma(\mu \mapsto \mu(A):A \in \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B})$.

Given a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{B}$, for any $\mu \in \mathcal{M}_2$, define $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu) \in \mathcal{M}_2$ to be the unique measure such that

- $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)$ agrees with $\mu$ on $\mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{B}$;
- there exists a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function $\nu \colon [0,1] \to \mathcal{M}$ such that for all $A_1,A_2 \in \mathcal{B}$,
  $$ \mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2) \ = \ \int_{A_1 \times [0,1]} \nu(x)(A_2) \, \mu(d(x,y)). $$

> > Is the map $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G} \colon \mathcal{M}_2 \to \mathcal{M}_2$ a measurable function? Or at the least, is $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}^{-1}(\mathcal{A})$ a universally measurable subset of $\mathcal{M}_2$ for every measurable set $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}_2$?

*Remark:* The existence and uniqueness of the measure $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)$ follows from the disintegration theorem applied to the measure $\mu|_{\mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{B}}$.

**UPDATE:** A simple "counting" argument as in the comments below yields that there must exist $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not measurable with respect to the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra. **Nonetheless, the key question remains as to whether $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is necessarily *universally* measurable (in the sense that the pre-image of every member of the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra belongs to the universal completion of the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra).**

[For an *explicit* example showing that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not necessarily continuous: Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the countable-cocountable algebra. Let $\rho_n$ be a sequence of atomless probability measures on $[0,1]$ converging weakly to a non-trivial purely atomic measure $\rho$. Writing $D \colon x \mapsto (x,x)$, we have that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(D_\ast\rho_n)=\rho_n \otimes \rho_n$ but $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(D_\ast\rho)=D_\ast\rho$.]

---

**A possible approach:** Fix $A_1$ and $A_2$. Given a finite or countable partition $\mathcal{H}$ of $[0,1]$ by members of $\mathcal{G}$, we can "approximate" $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2)$ by
$$ \mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2) \ \approx \ \mathbb{E}_{\sigma(\mathcal{H})}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2) \ = \ \sum_{G \in \mathcal{H}} \mu(G \times A_2)\mu((G \cap A_1) \times [0,1]). $$
Given an increasing sequence of such partitions $\mathcal{H}_n$ such that $\mathcal{G} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{N}_{\pi^1_\ast\mu} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{H}_n)$, Levy's upward theorem yields that $\mathbb{E}_{\sigma(\mathcal{H}_n)}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2) \to \mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2)$.

[Here, $\mathcal{N}_{\pi^1_\ast\mu}$ is the set of $\pi^1_\ast\mu$-null sets, where $\pi^1_\ast\mu(A):=\mu(A \times [0,1])$.]

Now such a sequence $\mathcal{H}_n$ always exists---based on the proof of the equivalence between "separable" and "countably generated mod 0" given [here](https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/lebesgue-probability-spaces-part-i/), I think the following construction works: Letting $\mathcal{U}$ be a countable algebra generating $\mathcal{B}$, let $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{G}$ be a countable set such that for every $U \in \mathcal{U}$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$, if $\mathcal{G}_{U,r}:=\{G \in \mathcal{G} : \mu(G \triangle U) < \frac{1}{r} \}$ is non-empty then $\exists \, i$ s.t. $G_i \in \mathcal{G}_{U,r}$. Then take $\mathcal{H}_n$ to be the partition generated by $\{G_1,\ldots,G_n\}$.

So then, to prove the desired result, it is sufficient to show that there is a sequence of "partition-valued" functions
$$ \mathcal{H}_n \colon \mathcal{M}_2 \to \ \{\textrm{finite or countable partitions contained in } \mathcal{G}\} $$
such that $\mu \mapsto \sum_{G \in \mathcal{H}_n(\mu)} \mu(G \times A_2)\mu((G \cap A_1) \times [0,1])$ is universally measurable for each $n$, and $\mathcal{G} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{N}_{\pi^1_\ast\mu} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{H}_n(\mu))$ for every $\mu$.

[*Remark:* One might hope that it could even be possible to take $\mathcal{H}_n$ to be independent of $\mu$. However, this is not possible in general. This follows from the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156998/is-every-sub-sigma-algebra-of-mathcalb-mathbbr-universally-countabl; but also, if it were possible to take $\mathcal{H}_n$ to be independent of $\mu$, then $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ would be measurable with respect to the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra, which we have established not always to be the case.]

---

**Another characterisation of $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2)$:**

In the above discussion *"A possible approach"*, I gave a sort-of-explicit construction of $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2)$, but the difficulty is that it relies on "making a choice" - which could then lead to measurability issues when we allow $\mu$ to vary.

Now one of the comments suggested looking directly at the proof of the disintegration theorem and hoping that the desired measurability might become more clear from there. Disintegration relies fundamentally on the Radon-Nikodym theorem; on the basis of the proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem, $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2)$ can be characterised as follows:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of $(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{B})$-measurable functions $g \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that for every $G \in \mathcal{G}$,
$$ \int_{G \times [0,1]} g(x) \, \mu(d(x,y)) \ \leq \ \mu(G \times A_2) \, ; $$
then
$$ \mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(\mu)(A_1 \times A_2) \ = \ \sup_{g \in \mathcal{C}} \int_{A_1 \times [0,1]} g(x) \, \mu(d(x,y)). $$

Again, it is difficult to see any measurability from this.

*Increasingly I am starting to suspect that (assuming the axiom of choice) there exists a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not universally measurable!*

Comment: In the integral, $\nu$ seems to be a function of both coordinates.

Comment: For each $x \in [0,1]$, $\nu(x)$ is a measure on $[0,1]$. An alternative way to write the integral is $\ \int_{A_1} \nu(x)(A_2) \, \pi_{1\ast}\mu(dx)\,$, where $\pi_1 \colon [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is the projection $\pi_1(x,y)=x$.

Comment: We probably just need to look at a constructive proof of the disintegration theorem, and the measurability may become obvious.  By the way, isn't the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra equal to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the weak topology?  That could be helpful; the conditioning map may turn out to be (semi)continuous or otherwise nice with respect to that topology.

Comment: Yes, the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra is precisely the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topology of weak convergence. I thought about the possibility of trying to use some kind of continuity property, but it felt unlikely to me that we would have such continuity, since $\mathcal{G}$ is an arbitrary sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Some kind of continuity with respect to total-variation distance seems more likely, but this generates the wrong $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: As for the proof of the disintegration theorem, I have a feeling there are genuine issues with measurability here, which can probably only be remedied if perhaps $\mathcal{G}$ is countably generated.

Comment: The idea that "everything that can be constructed is measurable" I think only really applies to standard Borel spaces, and the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ on which we apply the disintegration theorem is not standard. (Now this idea that constructivity implies measurability is precisely why I expect my question to have the answer "yes"; but I suspect that proving it via measurability of the disintegration procedure itself will not work.)

Comment: Certainly, at the least, I know that for general measurable spaces $G$ and $X$ with $X$ standard, there typically does *not* exist a measurable function $p:P\!r(G\times X)\times G\to P\!r(X)$ such that $p(\mu,\,\cdot\,)$ is a disintegration of $\mu$ for every $\mu$.

Comment: If one looks at the measures in $\mathcal{M}_2$ with a fixed marginal in the first coordinate, the answer is yes. This follows from arguments in [Random Probability Measures on Polish Spaces](https://www.crcpress.com/Random-Probability-Measures-on-Polish-Spaces/Crauel/p/book/9780415273879) by Hans Crauel, where that case is treated under the heading "Conditional Expectation of Random Measures". In that case, the function is actually continuous in the weak topology. Maybe one can adapt the arguments there to your problem, but it might take a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting to know. It does not surprise me; my intuition behind why I expect continuity to fail in the general setup (where the marginal can vary) is that the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ is unrelated to the topology of $[0,1]$. This seems unlikely to be problematic when we fix the marginal; but when we vary the marginal, I expect Crauel's arguments will only generalise if we equip the base space with a topology like that induced by the total-variation distance (i.e. ignoring the topology of the base space), but this will probably induce the wrong $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: One thing that's potentially alarming is that there are  $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{B}$, whereas there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ many Borel maps from $\mathcal{M}_2$ to itself.  (For instance, given any $A \subset [0,1]$, let $\mathcal{G}_A$ be generated by all the countable subsets of $A$.)  Is the map $\mathcal{G} \mapsto \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{G}}$ 1-1?

Comment: Wow, good question! If so, then this proves that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not necessarily a *Borel* map. However, what I am really keen to know is whether $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is *at least universally measurable* (in the sense that the pre-images of Borel sets are universally measurable). I think there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ universally measurable maps.

Comment: Well, at the least, for any $A,B\subset [0,1]$ with $|B\setminus A|\geq 2$, we have that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{G}_A}\neq\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{G}_B}$: Fix distinct $x,y\in B\setminus A$. Then $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{G}_B}(\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{(x,x)}+\delta_{(y,y)}))=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{(x,x)}+\delta_{(y,y)})$ but $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{G}_A}(\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{(x,x)}+\delta_{(y,y)}))=\frac{1}{4}(\delta_{(x,x)}+\delta_{(x,y)}+\delta_{(y,x)}+\delta_{(y,x)})$.

Comment: So, since the number of equivalence classes of $2^{[0,1]}$ under countable symmetric difference is larger than $\mathfrak{c}$ (I presume!), there exists $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not Borel-measurable. The question of universal measurability remains.

Comment: @JulianNewman Please give a reference for the disintegration theorem used in the statement of the question. Is the function $\nu$ really  $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, or is it measurable with respect to a completion of $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: @user95282 Yes $\nu$ is really $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. The version of the disintegration theorem which I am using is that for ***any*** probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, for any probability measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega\times [0,1],\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B})$ with $\mu( \,\cdot\, \times [0,1])=\mathbb{P}$, there exists an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function $\nu\colon\Omega\to [0,1]$ (unique up to $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. equality) such that $\mu(A)=\int_\Omega\int_{[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_A(\omega,x)\,\nu(\omega)(dx)\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: I believe this can be found in Proposition 3.6 of Crauel, *Random probability measures on Polish spaces*, although it cites some other book for the proof (if I recall correctly). I also have a proof in <a  href="https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk:8443/handle/10044/1/39569">my PhD thesis</a>, Lemma 3.27.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I can't get the hyperlink to work: the url for my PhD thesis is https-colon-//spiral.imperial.ac.uk-colon-8443/handle/10044/1/39569

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for your idea about considering $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ for $\sigma$-algebras of the form $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(\{x\}:x\in A)$ for arbitrary $A \subset [0,1]$. This has turned out to be exactly the basis of my proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I've worked out that the answer is **no**, i.e. there exists a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not universally measurable.

(We will write $\lambda$ for the Lebesgue measure on $([0,1],\mathcal{B})$.)

It is well-known that the evaluation $\sigma$-algebra is precisely the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topology of weak convergence, which is a Polish topology. So then, to show that (for some given $\mathcal{G}$) $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not universally measurable, it is sufficient (by Lusin's theorem) to find a probability measure $Q$ on $\mathcal{M}_2$ such that for every measurable set $E \subset \mathcal{M}_2$ with $Q(E)>0$, the restriction of $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ to $E$ is not a continuous function (with respect to the topology of weak convergence).

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be a set such that $A$ and $[0,1] \setminus A$ intersect every Lebesgue-positive measure set. (Assuming the axiom of choice, such a set $A$ exists, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2181942/is-there-a-set-a-subset-0-1-such-that-both-a-and-0-1-setminus-a-inte).) Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of all countable subsets of $A$ and their complements.

Let $Q$ be the image measure of $\lambda \otimes \lambda$ under the map $D : (x,y) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{x,x}+\delta_{y,y})$. Let $E \subset \mathcal{M}_2$ be any measurable set with $Q(E)>0$, and let $F=D^{-1}(E)$. (So $\lambda \otimes \lambda(F)>0$.) Let $F'=\{x \in [0,1] : \lambda(y:(x,y)\in F)>0\}$. Obviously $\lambda(F')>0$, so fix a point $x \in F' \setminus A$. For any $y \in [0,1]$, we have that
$$ \mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(D(x,y)) \ = \ \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{x,x}+\delta_{y,y}) & y \in A \\ \frac{1}{4}(\delta_{x,x} + \delta_{x,y} + \delta_{y,x} + \delta_{y,y}) & y \not\in A. \end{array} \right. $$
So since $Y:=\{y \in [0,1] : (x,y) \in F\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure, it is clear that $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}(D(x,\cdot))$ is not continuous on $Y$, so $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G} \circ D$ is not continuous on $F$, so (since $D$ is obviously continuous) $\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{G}$ is not continuous on $E$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we say the operation of conditioning on a sub $\sigma$ algebra is measurable as long as it is non-atomic w.r.t. any element in $\mathcal{M}$? Or is there any sufficient condition?